# Can you get a string returned from a Sentiment Ouptut

Tags: c#, ml.net

Im learning ML.net, i have already posted two questions about other things to do with ML.net. I have followed examples showing how to predict an outcome based on yes or no, true or false. But can you pull out a string value to say male or female.

Im picking this stuff up slowly but im understanding the model. How the context takes in the data and uses, algorithms, transformers, uses a prediction engine.

So if i had data such as age, annual wage, county they are from, job title. Can you return whether the person is a male or female consisting of the data from those columns i suggested.

```
gender     age     county     job     wage
--------------------------------------------
male       32      west       dev     34,000
male       28      south      front   28,000
female     40      south      back    33,000
male       24      east       dev     22,000
???        44      north      dev     55,000
```

So if i had the label as gender, and the rest of the data to give a prediction about the right gender.

How could i build the model for this outcome?

Comment: Does multi class specification come into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes and you can do that with Key-Value Mapping as explained in this doc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/prepare-data-ml-net#key-value-mapping